# Calling SageMath functions from Javascript

Tags: javascript, sage

I ask the question and I have to admit that I'm a bit confused on the way to be precise to ask the question... Sorry for that!

Anyhow, I'm using from time to time SageMath on a local machine. I have seen that SageMath is also offering access from a server [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/about.html?v=15adefe8b7e89fcf49eda7af5303abd4). If I understand well this is a way to access **SageMath interpreter** from a web browser.

But this doesn't provide access to the "base functions" of SageMath from JavaScript. That would be a kind of "wrapping" of SageMath basic functions in JavaScript calling a server. Is that possible?

Comment: Along related lines, you may be interested in how the iOS and Android Sage apps work - code is on github, I believe.  They function using an API of the cell server, so what you want should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage functions work with Sage structures (variables, matrices, functions, etc), which are not JavaScript objects. JavaScript does not have a thing to which you could apply Sage commands like `plot` or  `indefinite_integral`.

The mobile Sage apps work by sending user input to be parsed to Sage Cell Server, and displaying the HTML they get from the server.

Of course one could write JavaScript functions like

```
function integrate(fn, var, a, b) {
    var SageCommand = ['definite_integral('+fn, var, a, b+')'].join(); 
    // send SageCommand string to be parsed by Cell Server
    // parse the response and return the result of integration as a float
}
```

which would make it look like you are doing things in JS with JS objects. But this is just adding another wrapper, i.e., making access to Sage even less direct 
than it was. The bottom line is, Sage is not a JavaScript library.