# Is it possible to pass variables from JavaScript into embedded Sage code?

Tags: javascript, sage

I'm embedding a SageCell into my webpage. I want to be able to pass variables from inputs that I built using JavaScript. Is it possible to pass the JavaScript variables into the SageCell code?

Comment: Possibly related: [Stack Overflow question 29985377: Calling SageMath functions from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985377)

The [sage-cell mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-cell) might also be a good place to ask this question.

Comment: Try asking on the [sage-cell mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/sage-cell).